Make infinite carousel
I have this carousel that shows some text on the left and a full image and half of the other.
I need help to make my carousel infinite. That is, as I navigate with the next and previous buttons, the carousel flows infinitely, so that the carousel does not restart. I would appreciate any help.


let currentIndex = 0;
const prevBtn = document.querySelector('.prev');
const nextBtn = document.querySelector('.next');
const carouselInner = document.querySelector('.carousel-inner');
const totalImages = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel-inner img').length;

nextBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (currentIndex < totalImages - 1) {
    currentIndex++;
    carouselInner.style.transform = `translateX(-${currentIndex * 66.66}%)`;
  }
});

prevBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (currentIndex > 0) {
    currentIndex--;
    carouselInner.style.transform = `translateX(-${currentIndex * 66.66}%)`;
  }
});
.banner-section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

.text-content {
  width: 30%;
}

.category-label {
  color: #8a7f6e;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.text-content h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.text-content p {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.view-all-btn {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.carousel {
  position: relative;
  width: 65%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.carousel-inner {
  display: flex;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  width: calc(75% * 1.5);
}

.carousel-inner img {
  width: calc(100% / 1.5);
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.carousel-inner img:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.carousel-btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: white;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.carousel-btn.prev {
  left: 10px;
}

.carousel-btn.next {
  right: 10px;
}
<div class="banner-section">
  <div class="text-content">
    <p class="category-label">Popular Categories</p>
    <h1>We believe in giving back, today and everyday</h1>
    <p>We collaborate with local animal welfare groups to provide essential resources and assistance to pets in need.</p>
    <button class="view-all-btn">VIEW ALL</button>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0652/1238/3477/files/Rectangle_7.png">
      <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0652/1238/3477/files/Rectangle_7.png">
      <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0652/1238/3477/files/Rectangle_7.png">
      <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0652/1238/3477/files/Rectangle_7.png">
    </div>
    <button class="carousel-btn prev">&#10094;</button>
    <button class="carousel-btn next">&#10095;</button>
  </div>
</div>




What have you done to try and add this functionality?

Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question.

the carousel flows infinitely,, if you have finite number of elements how you want to achieve infinite scroll without restarting:

In your code, when click next or before buttons, you didn't allowed the action if the index is not available. But to make it like infinite loop, I allowed the action and updated currentIndex with first or last index of images.


let currentIndex = 0;
const prevBtn = document.querySelector('.prev');
const nextBtn = document.querySelector('.next');
const carouselInner = document.querySelector('.carousel-inner');
const totalImages = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel-inner img').length;

function moveToSlide(index) {
    carouselInner.style.transition = 'transform 0.5s ease-in-out';
    carouselInner.style.transform = `translateX(-${index * 66.66}%)`;
}

nextBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    currentIndex++;
    if (currentIndex >= totalImages) {
        currentIndex = 0;
    }
    moveToSlide(currentIndex);
});

prevBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    currentIndex--;
    if (currentIndex < 0) {
        currentIndex = totalImages - 1;
    }
    moveToSlide(currentIndex);
});
.banner-section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

.text-content {
  width: 30%;
}

.category-label {
  color: #8a7f6e;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.text-content h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.text-content p {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.view-all-btn {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.carousel {
  position: relative;
  width: 65%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.carousel-inner {
  display: flex;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  width: calc(75% * 1.5);
}

.carousel-inner img {
  width: calc(100% / 1.5);
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.carousel-inner img:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.carousel-btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: white;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.carousel-btn.prev {
  left: 10px;
}

.carousel-btn.next {
  right: 10px;
}
<div class="banner-section">
  <div class="text-content">
    <p class="category-label">Popular Categories</p>
    <h1>We believe in giving back, today and everyday</h1>
    <p>We collaborate with local animal welfare groups to provide essential resources and assistance to pets in need.</p>
    <button class="view-all-btn">VIEW ALL</button>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0652/1238/3477/files/Rectangle_7.png">
      <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0652/1238/3477/files/Rectangle_7.png">
      <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0652/1238/3477/files/Rectangle_7.png">
      <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0652/1238/3477/files/Rectangle_7.png">
    </div>
    <button class="carousel-btn prev">&#10094;</button>
    <button class="carousel-btn next">&#10095;</button>
  </div>
</div>




This answer could be improved by explaining what you changed and why. I also don't think this is what the desired functionality is. I think they're not looking for it to go back to the beginning, but instead always advance to the right with the images cycling.

I think the OP is looking to loop when it gets to the end... e.g. user starts seeing 1,2,3,4... then scrolls to the right to see 5,6,7,8 but if 8 is the last item, it should roll over to show... 7,8,1,2 etc.
